# Under winsock2, what alternative is there to select()?

Tags: winsock, winsock2

I have a working multi-client, single-threaded TCP/IP server application built in C++ over bare winsock2. The heart of it uses `select()` to wait for new work to do. I'm thinking of extending the number of simultaneous clients to some hundreds or thousands, in practice all mostly idle. My architecture uses very little memory for a connected, idle client.

Before each `select()`, I build an `fd_set` of client sockets in read state, plus my listening socket (for accepting new connections); and another `fd_set` of sockets in write state. Then, after the `select()`, I scan these to reconstruct, from the socket number, which of my client that was for. This `fd_set` building and scanning, though objectively not the current CPU bottleneck, makes me uneasy: the amount of work per transaction grows linearly with the number of clients; and while I see how to go over the default 64-sockets limit in an `fd_set`, I'm reluctant to go that route.

I vaguely see how I could use two threads, one  handling  the few most active clients, and another for the bulk of idle clients. That seems workable, but a tad complex.

So: what are the alternatives to `select()` under winsock2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have seen, `select()` has a max limit for the number of sockets it can handle in a single call.  If scalability is an issue for you then you should use Overlapped I/O or I/O Completion Ports instead.  That way, you can issue read/write operations on individual sockets when needed and the OS will notify you when the work is finished, there is no need to poll for it.